# HTML5 W3C valid tel hyperlink

Tags: html, validation

I have a quick question - I'm adding in telephone links to the numbers on my website and am wondering how to get it to successfully pass W3C validation? The following syntax:

```
<a href="tel: 0141 123456">0141 123456</a>
```

returns the following markup error:

Bad value tel:01292 477198 for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in scheme data: not a URL code point.

Any suggestions would be more than welcome :)

Graham

Comment: Try to remove the spaces inside the href and re-validate it

Comment: Perfect, that was indeed the problem. Thank you andrew :)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else encounters this old issue.

Removing the space inside the href resolves the validation problem.

For those interested, the RFC with the full specification is here:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2806